# How can one find all the adjacent vertices, given a table of vertices with a specific rectangle format?

Tags: c++, data-structures

If I have a table of vertexes represented by:

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
m n o p
```

How can I get the adjacencies of a node as indexes, if the indexes for this table is as follows:

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
12 13 14 15
```

For example, node "a" should result: 1, 4, 5. node "f" results in 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10.
How can this be expanded to a table of any size? This is a 4x4, what about a 10x10? 3x4?
Can this be found with code? c++ preferred.

So far I tried: Since it's a 4x4 I tried subtracting 4 and adding 4 from the index of the node in question. However, this does not work for every node, especially the edge and corner nodes.

Comment: How are you determining the adjacencies? Is it supposed to be a square grid?

Comment: I reformatted the question, it was supposed to be in block quotes, does that help?

Comment: That helps, what have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried? @TheEngineer

Comment: Since it's a 4x4 I tried subtracting 4 and adding 4 from the index of the node in question. However, this does not work for every node, especially the edge and corner nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, every node is connected to 8-directional way. So we will try to get grid number of 8 adjacent cells.

```
// starting from upper left corner for a cell
int dr[8]  = {-1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0};  // 8 direction row
int dc[8]  = {-1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1};  // 8 direction column

int n = 20;
int m = 30;

int r = 1, c = 1;   // position of 'f' is (1, 1)

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    int adjr = r + dr[i];
    int adjc = c + dc[i];
    if (adjr < 0 || adjr >= n || adjc < 0 || adjc >= m) continue;  // check for invalid cells

    cout << adjr << " " << adjc << endl;  // {row, column} which is connected
}
```

Outputs:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 2
2 2
2 1
2 0
1 0
```

These cells are connected to (1,1).

Comment: What do n and m represent here? How did you get 20 and 30, respectively?

Comment: Also, this does not work in some cases. For example if I put r=3, c= 3 for position [3, 3], the last vertex, it gives incorrect vertexes.

Comment: This works fine. You need to understand where you should change to get correct outputs. 
Okay let me explain.
n = number of row in the grid.
m = number of column in the grid.
r = row number of the cell for whom you want to get connected cells.
c = column number of the cell for whom you want to get connected cells. 
So change it like this to get your expected output:
`n = 4, m = 4, r = 3, c = 3;`
This should work.